# Get orders of a user with orderItems and product details in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables (foods, orders and orderItems). I want to get orders of a user with orderItems and foods, but i failed.

Here's a result what i am getting right now, but i need to get food details instead of food_id.

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "user_id": 2,
        "total": "12.50",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "order_id": 16,
                "food_id": 1,
                "quantity": 1,
                "food_price": "12.50",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

OrderController

```
$user = Auth::user();
return response()->json($user->deliveredOrders()->with('items')->get());
```

User Model

```
public function deliveredOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class)->where('status', '=', 'delivered');
}
```

Order Model

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define food() method on OrderItem model.

```
public function food() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Food');
}
```

And get relation data using this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
return response()->json($user->deliveredOrders()->with('items.food')->get());
```

Comment: Thanks, I had "hasOne" instead of "belongsTo". Got it. :)
 public function food(){
        return $this->hasOne(Food::class);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You should create this relationship in the OrderItem model

```
public function food() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Food'); //or wherever you have the model 
}
```

and then get it

```
$user = Auth::user();
return response()->json($user->deliveredOrders()->with('items.food')->get());
```